# Android Picasso Framework, load images asynchronously

Tags: android, image, listview, frameworks

I have tried to inplement the "Picasso Framework" in my MainActivity, but it keeps giving me an error. It is in this line "Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)", the "Picasso" has an red line under it. Can someone please help me. I have imported the jar.file.

Please look at my code:

```
package com.chrfugl.xxxx;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import com.chrfugl.studenterhuset.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Vector<RowData> data;
RowData rd;

public static final String[] title = new String[] {
        "1", 
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5, 
        "6",
        };

public static final String[] detail = new String[] {
    "Text",
    "Text",
    "Text",
    "Text",
    "Text",
    "Text",
    };

public static Integer[] imgid = { 
    R.drawable.1, R.drawable.2, 
    R.drawable.3, R.drawable.4, 
    R.drawable.5, R.drawable.6, 

};

public static final String[] footer = new String[] {
    "Text", 
    "Text",
    "\Text",
    "\Text",
    "\Text",
    "\Text",
    }; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)     getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    data = new Vector<RowData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {

        try {
            rd = new RowData(i, title[i], detail[i]);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        data.add(rd);
    }
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.title, data);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private class RowData {
    protected int mId;
    protected String mTitle;
    protected String mDetail;

    RowData(int id, String title, String detail) {
        mId = id;
        mTitle = title;
        mDetail = detail;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mId + " " + mTitle + " " + mDetail;
    }
}

private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {

        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        TextView title = null;
        TextView detail = null;
        ImageView i11 = null;
        RowData rowData = getItem(position);
        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        title = holder.gettitle();
        title.setText(rowData.mTitle);
        detail = holder.getdetail();
        detail.setText(rowData.mDetail);

        i11 = holder.getImage();
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
        .load(imgid[rowData.mId])
        .placeholder(android.R.color.black)
        .error(android.R.color.black)
        .resize(100, 100)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(i11);
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private View mRow;
        private TextView title = null;
        private TextView detail = null;
        private ImageView i11 = null;

        public ViewHolder(View row) {
            mRow = row;
        }

        public TextView gettitle() {
            if (null == title) {
                title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
            }
            return title;
        }

        public TextView getdetail() {
            if (null == detail) {
                detail = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.detail);
            }
            return detail;
        }

        public ImageView getImage() {
            if (null == i11) {
                i11 = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.img);
            }
            return i11;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm doing something similar HERE!!!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808114/picasso-loading-of-image-spawned-inside-asynctask

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

Edit your `CustomAdapter` class by adding a `private Context` variable. Then, in the constructor of the `CustomAdapter`, initialize that variable.

Then you will have a `Context` to reference every time you need to make a `Picasso` call.

So, Custom Adapter should look like this:

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {

    private Context mContext;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {

        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mContext = context;

    }...
```

Then make Picasso calls in `getView()` like this"

`Picasso.with(mContext)...` and add whatever else you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you explain me the bit with the getView()? I am not sure what you want me to do?

And thanks for your answer!

Comment: Your Picasso call looks fine as it is right now in getView(). I think your problem may actually be that you aren't importing the Picasso library. `Try adding import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;` to your imports.

Comment: Hi again. I have now imported picasso, and now the error is gone, so thank you! But when i try to run the app on my device (nexus 4) it crashes when booting. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: And should i not edit my CustomAdapter then, as you said in your first answer?

Comment: I would need to see the Log as to why your app is crashing. Also- you can edit your CustomAdapter, but I'm not sure its necessary. I would do it just to be safe.

Comment: I have tried to run the app again and it still wont open. I have edited the CustomAdapter, but that did not help. You can see my log here: http://i.imgur.com/vKaxm3h.jpg

Comment: It seems to me that you didn't import the Picasso .jar file properly.
Copy and paste the .jar file you downloaded into your libs folder in your project. Then, right click the .jar and select Build Path > Add to Build Path. 

Then see what happens!

Comment: I have tried it again, several times, but it just wont work. I dont get it? :(

Comment: Make sure Android Private Libraries and Android Dependencies are checked on the Order and Export tab in the Java Build Path section of the project's properties.